# Randomizing miltidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2-dimentional array with 30+ item nodes in the following format.

```
$catalog= array(
    array(
        code => "ABC",
        name => "Item name",
        link => "domain.com/item121"
    ),
    array(
        code => "DEF",
        name => "Another item name",
        link => "domainB.com/item333"
    )
);
```

I need to do the following:

1. Randomize the array
2. Display the first 5 items in a row
3. Display the rest inside another container 5 items per row.

I only want to show complete rows of 5 and no partials. So I count the total items:

```
$items= count($catalog);
```

Then I count how many to display to have complete rows of 5:

```
$showItems = floor($logosN / 5) * 5; // num or rows * cnt per row
```

I am not sure how to do the rest. I am able to output the items without randomizing

```
echo '<div class="first5">';
     // 5 first items here
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="restItems">';
// rest items need to go here

for ($x = 0; $x <= $showItems - 1; $x++) {
    echo '
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_'.$catalog[$x][code].'"></div>
    </div>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

Need some help here. Thanks.

Comment: If you're able to do it without randomizing, just call `array_shuffle()` and use the same procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the examples posted by the users on the PHP documentation for `shuffle` and found this function, which *if I understand your question correctly* does what you want:

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php#93214

```
<?php
function twodshuffle($array)
{
    // Get array length
    $count = count($array);
    // Create a range of indicies
    $indi = range(0,$count-1);
    // Randomize indicies array
    shuffle($indi);
    // Initialize new array
    $newarray = array($count);
    // Holds current index
    $i = 0;
    // Shuffle multidimensional array
    foreach ($indi as $index)
    {
        $newarray[$i] = $array[$index];
        $i++;
    }
    return $newarray;
}
?>
```

Please note it only works on two dimensional arrays.
Also, note that it will not shuffle the actual inner array elements, but only shuffle the outer array, *if you know what I mean*, and *if I know what you want* ;)